# Html content not formatted while external share android

Tags: android, html

Hi I use to share the below content

```
<html>
 <head>
  <style type="text/css"> 
   @font-face { 
       font-family: MyFont; 
       src: url("file:///android_asset/fonts/opensans_regular.ttf") 
   } 
   body { 
       font-family: MyFont; 
       text-align: justify; 
       color: #000000; 
   } 
  </style> 
 </head>
  <body><font size=6>
<h3><strong>Journée Do it yourself !</strong></h3>
<p><strong>Samedi 5 novembre</strong></p>
<p>Le “Do It Yourself” est le mouvement du “faire soi-même” regroupant celles et ceux qui, inventifs, bricoleurs et débrouillards, souhaitent s’exprimer, expérimenter et partager leur savoir-faire.<br />
<strong>Vous voulez animer des ateliers créatifs à la médiathèque ?</strong> Cette journée est pour vous ! Couture, tricot, customisation, récup, Fab’lab, imprimante 3D… toutes les créations sont possibles !<br />
<strong>Alors n’hésitez pas à nous solliciter avant le 30 septembre pour participer à cet événement inédit en venant partager votre passion ou votre savoir-faire.</strong><br />
Contact : Sophie Bourgeois</p>
<ul>
<li>01.34.58.12.19</li>
<li><a href="mailto:sophiebourgeois@velizy-villacoublay.fr">sophiebourgeois@velizy-villacoublay.fr</a></li>
</ul>
  </font></body>
</html>
```

to external app using below code

```
  sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(body)+"\n "+appendContent);
```

I use to load this body string in webview as well as in external share. But both format get differ. I want to share it in external app like the format i'm seeing in webview. Could you please suggest me any idea to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: From documentation: [Html.fromHtml()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml(java.lang.String)): `Returns displayable styled text from the provided HTML string with the legacy flags`. No tags are left, then the other "webview" gets a single `String`, and renders it. Please, Log the `Intent` extra you are sending

Comment: @Bonatti I have added the log at very first which i'm passing in intent.

Comment: Again: Debug your application, add breakpoints before/after `sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(body)+"\n "+appendContent);` press send,/share/whatever, copy the value in the Intent.Extra field (a `String`), post on your question. It appears that no tags are being set, if they are, then they are not being rendered, if they are, then your WebView has any different parameter. We need to focus on finding the issue before resolving each and all possible problems.

Answer (score 0):

### You can use this to mail your Text

//SendEmail is Email  Send Btn ID

```
protected void sendEmail() { 
    Log.i("Send email", "");
    String[] TO = {""};
    String[] CC = {""};
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

    emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
    emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, TO);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, CC);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, " Your Subject");
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, " Your Text Here");
    emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");

    try {
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
        finish();
    }
    catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        Toast.makeText(CurrentActivityName.this, "There is no email client installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using android studio

Answer (score 0):

> I use to share the below content... to external app using below code

You are using `Html.fromHtml()`. That supports a limited number of HTML tags. It does not support stylesheets and Web fonts. Also, only on Android 7.0+ might it handle lists.

Plus, once you append your `appendContent`, you no longer have valid HTML, as you have text outside the `</html>` tag.

So, focus on using valid HTML with very limited formatting. [This blog post of mine](https://commonsware.com/blog/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html) lists most of the tags supported by `Html.fromHtml()` prior to Android 7.0.